# Is there an event for zoom in/out on HERE map API?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I need to listen to zoom events on the map.

I have already tried to use 'mapviewchange' event, but it is not meant to listen only to zoom event.

I was wondering if there is a 'zoom, zoomstart, zoomend' event

```
map.addEventListener('zoomstart', evt => {
  console.log(evt);
});
```

I expect an event to only listen to zoom events, not any other events on the map.

Answer (score 1):

Here doesnt provide separate zoomstart, zoomend events. But you can identify zoom events using mapviewchangeend event.Below is a sample code on how you can do it. Hope this helps!

```
var oldZoom=map.getZoom();
map.addEventListener('mapviewchangeend', function(){
     var newZoom=map.getZoom();
     if(newZoom > oldZoom){
      // zoomed in
     }else{
      // zoomed out
     }
     oldZoom=newZoom;
})
```

Comment: But what about if we have changed the zoom level at some point in the meantime? e.g : Render a new position on the map.

The problem with 'mapviewchangeend' is that it would listen to other events as well.